# how do i get this before/after slider to work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I'm trying to get [this plug in](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vsBzo) to work, but something isn't right.

here's the issue: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dIGFsBBcdTQ&feature=youtu.be

This is the `<head>` of my HTML document:

```
<script> 

var $after = $('.after'),
        img_width = $('.after img').width(),
        init_split = Math.round(img_width/2);

  $after.width(init_split);  

        $('.before_after_slider').mousemove(function(e){
        var offX  = (e.offsetX || e.clientX - $after.offset().left);
            $after.width(offX);
        });

        $('.before_after_slider').mouseleave(function(e){
        $after.stop().animate({
        width: init_split
        },1000)
        });

</script>
```

This is the body:

```
 <div class="before_after_slider">
      <div class="before">
        <img src="center_before.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" alt="before" />
      </div>
      <div class="after">
        <img src="center_after.jpg" width="100%" height="100%"  alt="after" />
      </div>
    </div>
```

And this is the CSS

```
.before_after_slider {
  position: relative;

  & > * {
    position: absolute;
  }
}

.after {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: [***DOCUMENT READY***](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: @adeneo ok now js is working but the slider is moving the second image laterally and it's not on top of the other..

Comment: ok. I'm new to JS so do you have any tips for what to mess with?

Comment: Change the styles in the CSS to get the right positioning.

Comment: @adeneo this is what's happening.. don't think it's just CSS http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dIGFsBBcdTQ&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 0):

Call function when DOM gets ready.

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $after = $('.after'),
        img_width = $('.after img').width(),
        init_split = Math.round(img_width / 2);

    $after.width(init_split);

    $('.before_after_slider').mousemove(function (e) {
        var offX = (e.offsetX || e.clientX - $after.offset().left);
        $after.width(offX);
    });

    $('.before_after_slider').mouseleave(function (e) {
        $after.stop().animate({
            width: init_split
        }, 1000)
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks! here's the issue now. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dIGFsBBcdTQ&feature=youtu.be